# Replace() with Split()

Tags: javascript

I need to enter a "0" in case there's only one digit after the comma, how does **replace()** work in this situation?

```js
var a = "2x 250,5";

console.log(a.replace(a.split(",")[1], a.split(",")[1] + 0));

//expected result
// 2x 250,50

//Output
//2x 2500,5
```

Comment: Your code is replacing the first `"0"` it finds.

Comment: `a.split(",")[1]` -> `0`. If you replace `0` with `00` in 2x 25**0**,0 that's what you'd get. Not sure why you expect this to be different. Moreover, if you're splitting already, just use the split value, and join it together, instead of replacing.

Comment: Do you need 01 or 10 ?

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi 10

Comment: @VLAZ "Not sure why you expect this to be different" because I didn't understand how the replace() function actually works. I was thinking that, with split, only what's after the comma would be replaced.

Comment: But *why*? You tell `replace` to work with `0` not with a specific position. There is nothing at all here that will specify "work on this exact character". A zero is a zero in a string. There is no "zero for position `n`". And even more generally, there is no "character for position `n`".

Comment: Like i said, i hadn't understood how it worked, but now I did. thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could search for a comma, digit and end of string and add a zero at the end.

```js
var a = "2x 250,0";

console.log(a.replace(/,\d$/, '$&0'));
```

Comment: This will add a zero at the end.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
a.replace(/,\d$/, x => x+'0');
```

```js
var tests = [
  '2x 250,0',
  '2x 200,03',
  '2x 511,0',
  '2x 413,3'
]
function addZero(str){
  return str.replace(/,\d$/, x => x+'0');
}
tests.forEach(str => console.log(addZero(str)));
```

Comment: Nice one, Nice one

Answer (score 1):

```js
let a = "2x 250,0";

console.log([a.split(','), a.split(',').pop().length===1 ? '0':null].join(''));
```

Comment: But better to use another variable instead twice split, just for inline.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = "2x 250,1",
splitvar = ","
a.split(splitvar)[1].length==1 && (a = a.replace(splitvar+a.split(splitvar)[1], ","+a.split(splitvar)[1] + 0))
console.log(a);
```

Comment: This replaces `250,15` with `250,150`.

Comment: oh i understand